# Finding minimum number for each element in 2 lists of integers in Python

Tags: python, loops

I need to write Python code that compares/relays through 2 lists of integers and then prints the smaller number of each element. I currently have this:

```
    x = range(0, 2**32)
    y = range(2**32, 2**64)
    def minimum(a, b):
       """print the minimum for each element of 2 lists of integers"""
       for i in (a,b):
          print(min(a, b))
```

I am getting an error which reads :

> "'<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'."

Is there another way to solve my problem without the range function?

Comment: Simply `min(i)`.

Comment: @ForceBru My crystal ball suggest `for i, j in zip(a, b): print(min(i, j))`.

Comment: Side note: You don't want to iterate over ranges with `2**64` as upper boundary.  It tends to take a few thousand years.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, `range(2**32)` will be exhausted quite a bit before the second range, so as long as you don't use `itertools.zip_longest` you'll be fine

Comment: @SvenMarnach That worked perfectly-I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x = range(0, 2**32)
y = range(2**32, 2**64)

new_list = map(min, zip(x, y))

print(list(new_list))
```

new_list now stores the minimum values for every index of both lists.

Comment: In Python 3, `new_list` isn't actually a list.

Comment: I understand. I merely picked the name "new_list" on the fly.

Comment: @Ajax1234 thank you! Unfortunately I am now getting a memory error. I have never had this before-do you have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You are attempting to create a generator which, despite its efficiency, is still trying to crunch a list that for x, will be of length 4e9, and the last, which is approximately 1.8e19, which is greater than the estimated amount of grains of sand in the universe!

Comment: @H.Minear You are creating a list with 4 billion integers.  This would require hundreds of gigabytes of memory (at least on a 64-bit machine).

Comment: @Ajax1234 In Python 3, the size of the second range won't be relevant, since `zip()` stops once the shorter iterable is exhausted.  (In Python 2, the code wil already error out in the first line, so the size of the second iterable doesn't matter either.)

Comment: I did not know that about Python3. Thank you.

Comment: @H.Minear A work-around is to use the code I gave in the comment to your question.  It won't try to store all integers at the same time, but rather immediately print each integer as it goes along.  Be warned, though, that it will take a while to finish, and will be rather boring to watch.

Comment: @Ajax1234 `zip()` stops once the shorter iterable is exhausted in any version of Python.  The difference is really in the behaviour of `range()`: In Python 2, it returns a list, while in Python 3 it returns an abstract `range` object that can be iterated without creating and storing all the integer up front.